# How to disable save button and input field on click of save button and redirect to new page?

Tags: jquery, jsp

This is my form page. When i click on save button then the input field and the save button should be disable and to submit form it is directed to message.jsp and if i click on edit button then input field and save button should be enabled and for edit content should redirect to message1.jsp page.But nothing is happening.Please tell me what I am doing wrong I am new to these things.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>ed</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn1").click(function () {
                $("#tt1").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("#btn1").attr('disabled', true);
                window.location.href = "message.jsp";
            });
           $('#btn2').click(function () {
              $('#tt1').removeAttr('disabled');
              $('#btn1').removeAttr('disabled');
      
          });
    });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>

<form id="answer">
  <input type="text" value="xyz" id="tt1" /><br />
  <button type="submit" id="btn1">Save</button>
  <button type="submit" id="btn2">Edit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** What I want is,when click on save, all fields and save button become disabled and redirect to a Servletcontroller for form submission(I took message.jsp as example)and then redirect to somewhere else according to code.And when I again open this page all fields and save button should be disabled until and unless click on edit button.
**EDIT 2:** what I want is when page is loaded for the first time everything should be enabled, after click on save, save button n field should disable and when i again open that page for edit, after clicking on edit button then only disabled fields should be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly currently you are just redirecting to other page without submitting .If you need to `submit` value to next page you can just change `action` of your form to required page and then submit your form to that page with values .Also if you need value to be available at your other page you need to use `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#tt1").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#btn1").attr('disabled', true);
    //change action to message.jsp
    $("#answer").attr('action', 'message.jsp');
  $("#answer").submit(); //submit
   
  });
  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    $('#tt1').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#btn1').removeAttr('disabled');
   //change action to message1.jsp
   $("#answer").attr('action', 'message1.jsp');
  $("#answer").submit(); //submit
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="answer" action="">
  <input type="text" value="xyz" id="tt1"  /><br />
  <button type="submit" id="btn1" >Save</button>
  <button type="submit" id="btn2">Edit</button>
</form>
```

**Update 1** :

You can store values of which button is clicked using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and when your page will load again you can check the value save in `localStorage` and depending on this disable or enable you button.

Your **jquery** code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //check if there is any value in localStorage
  if (localStorage.getItem("save") != null) {
    //get that value
    var value = localStorage.getItem("save");
    alert(value);
    //if value is btn1
    if (value == "btn1") {
      //disable
      $("#tt1").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $("#" + value).attr('disabled', true);

    } else {
      //enable
      $('#tt1').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#btn1').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  }
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#tt1").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#btn1").attr('disabled', true);
    var save = "btn1";
    console.log(save);
    localStorage.clear(); //clear previous data
    localStorage.setItem("save", save); //add data to storage
    //change action to message.jsp
    $("#answer").attr('action', 'message.jsp');
    $("#answer").submit(); //submit

  });
  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    $('#tt1').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#btn1').removeAttr('disabled');
    var save = "btn2";
    console.log(save);
    localStorage.clear(); //clear previous data
    localStorage.setItem("save", save); //add data to storage
    //change action to message1.jsp
    $("#answer").attr('action', 'message1.jsp');
    $("#answer").submit(); //submit
  });
});
```

Comment: It is redirecting correctly but enable/disable not working.I have edited my question and code.plz look into that, if u understood what I want.Thanks for this.

Comment: everything is working fine but all fields and save button is disabled when i load the page for the first time , what i want is when page is loaded for the first time everything should be enabled after click on save, save button n field should disable and when i again open that page for edit, after clicking on edit button then only disabled fields should be enabled.

Comment: You can add one more value in localStorage which will check if page load for the first time ..if yes then don't add attribute else add attribute